# UITableView changes sizes when rotated from portrait, to landscape, back to portrait

Tags: ios, uitableview, rotation

I have a custom sized UITableView, which I set to a certain width & height, in portrait mode. However, when I rotate to landscape, then back to portrait, the table inexplicably increases in size (even though in the :
     willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

function, I set it to the same width and height as when I first loaded the table (in portrait mode)

Thanks,
sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to change the auto resizing mask

```
[tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone]
```